# Django Nginx: Gives WARNING:django.request:Not Found: When running server

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, waitress

I am trying to use Nginx with django to run my server but when i try to run i get these `WARNING:django.request:Not Found:` errors. normal `python manage.py runserver` works fine. Also i used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBKq6H9Rm5g).  Any idea why i am getting these errrors and how to fix them?

**Full Traceback**

```
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 1
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /robots.txt
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /robots.txt
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /.env
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
Not Found: /HNAP1/
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /.env
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /HNAP1/
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
Not Found: /HNAP1/
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 4
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /HNAP1/
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 5
Not Found: /.env
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /.env
Not Found: /.env
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /.env
Not Found: /assets/global/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/index.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /assets/global/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server    /php/index.php
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 1
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
Not Found: /favicon.ico
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /.env
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /favicon.ico
Not Found: /robots.txt
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 4
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /.env
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /robots.txt
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 2
Not Found: /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /api/jsonws/invoke
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 4
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /api/jsonws/invoke
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 3
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 4
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 5
WARNING:waitress.queue:Task queue depth is 6
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /config/getuser
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /config/getuser
Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /boaform/admin/formLogin
Not Found: /echo.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /echo.php
Not Found: /echo.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /echo.php
Not Found: /echo.php
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /echo.php
```

**Settings**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

**rme_nginx.conf**

```
# configuration of the server
server {
# the port your site will be served on
listen      80;
# the domain name it will serve for
server_name servername; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
location /media  {
   alias https://bucket.amazonaws.com/media/;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
}

location /static {
    alias https://bucket.amazonaws.com/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # See output from runserver.py
}
}
```

**runserver.py**

```
from waitress import serve

from myapp.wsgi import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, host = 'localhost', port='8080')
```